# Какой проект выбрать, чтобы создать виджет?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Какой проект нужно создать в *android studio*, чтобы получить на выходе *виджет*?

Answer (score 2):

В текущей стабильной студии (1.3.2) проекта именно для виджета нет. Выберите пустой проект без активити и поправьте его, как указано в документации
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html
Можно за основу взять какой-нибудь пример с виджетом из сдк.

Answer (score 0):

Обычный проект,  только есть нюансы.
Activity Вам не понадобится, поэтому не забудьте убрать галку Create Activity в визарде создания нового проекта. Пример создания смотрите по ссылке ниже.

http://startandroid.ru/en/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/195-urok-117-vidzhety-sozdanie-lifecycle
все подробно написано как создавать